# Reload div in jss, jquery

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a problem that when I use the loop to loop the elements in the session array it still runs normally, I try to use the code to reload only the shopping cart item, it reloads the cart, but it doesn't run. The PHP loop and my shopping cart are empty, what should I do?

```
<span id="soluonghang" class="badge badge-primary" style="background: #da251c;">
    <?php echo $soluongsanpham; ?>
</span>
<div class="popup" id="giocart">
    <div class="row header">
        <span>Items</span>
        <span>Amount</span>
    </div>

    <?php
    if (isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
        foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $value) {
            ?>
            <div class="row items" id="itcart">
                <span><?php echo $value['name']; ?></span>
                <span><?php echo $a = ($value['dongia'] * $value['num']) - ($value['giam'] / 100 * ($value['dongia'] * $value['num'])) ?>đ</span>
            </div>

            <?php
        }
    } else {
    }
    ?>
    
    <div class="row checkout">
        <span><a href="./cart.php">Đi đến giỏ hàng ></a></span>
        <span class="checkout-button" onclick="refesf()">Refesh giỏ hàng</span>
    </div>
</div>
</span>
```

Comment: What javascript are you referring to?

Comment: ```$('#giocart').load("http://localhost:8080/severr/cart.php  #itcart");``` my code i used to reload my cart

Comment: May you add that to the question?